# RegularExpression validation not validating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In the model I have the following property:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// MT Currency
    /// </summary>
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$", 
         ErrorMessage="Currency should be the 3 letter ISO 4217 currnecy")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
```

But it seems that it is not taken into account. If I enter input like "AUD+" nothing happen and the form is correctly validated.

It seems to happen only with the `RegularExpression` attribute because other properties of my form are correctly validated.

EDIT: I got one element of response. The form object that is display is not in the same assembly then the controller/view. For some reason when put it back in the same assembly I can see the validation attribute in the html. So the question remain. Is it possible to display the validation when the object is in another assembly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked whether the validation code is rendered in your HTML?

Comment: What should I expect? It does not seems to be the case.

Comment: Unless I much mistake, there should be *some* regex-related attributes on the rendered textbox, such as the error message text.  Are there any?

Comment: nop :(, ok so I guess only server side validation is happening.

Comment: But wait if only client side validation is perform that is not good either. It does not prevent a user to bypass client validation...